# How to flag this question?

Tags: discussion

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280941/python-you-must-read-the-data-using-raw-input-and-then-convert-it) question just now. I'm sure it needs flagging, but am not sure how to flag it.

The OP, basically, is asking why their code is failing an on-line automated code-testing system.

The code works, it gives the correct answer, but this answer is not arrived at by the 'correct' means, according to this automated system.

I'd say it is off-topic, but none of the close-reasons seem to fit. I was tempted by 'Blatantly off-topic' because the actual problem does have nothing to do with programming, rather it is a problem caused by *someone else's* sloppy programming.

Or is this just a down-vote and move-on situation?

Comment: If you really want to flag it, I'd say _Off topic_ > _Can no longer be reproduced_, since this is a problem specific to the OP's environment (automated test system), and it's also unlikely to help future readers. (unless they're doing the same assignment with the same automated test system..)

Comment: @JonasCz But the problem *can* still be reproduced, so that's just not true.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm with Servy on this one, it *can* be reproduced (just only by the OP).

Comment: Not sure I quite agree with the dupe, as the code itself didn't need debugging. The consensus in the linked question and answer does seem to be that which has also been suggested by Servy, below, however. So I'll go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a close reason specifically covering a question not describing the problem with the code:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Thank you. I was just about to comment with a rebuttal including something about how there was even an MCVE included when I realised that the 'V' was missing. The example isn't verifiable except by the OP (or anyone else using the same system).